# How do I re-enable swipe to unlock?

Tags: lock-screens, security, encryption

I recently encrypted my Android 4.4.2 device (S4 Active) and have now unencrypted it. However the only options I still have to unlock my phone are PIN and Password. When I attempt to change it it now states that swipe is turned off by; Administrator Policy, Encryption Policy, or Credential Storage.

How do I go about setting this back to how it was? Is it even possible or am I stuck using PIN or password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my phone had never fully decrypted. I went through the encryption process again then RE-decrypted it and I was able to switch back to swipe method.I am running a stock ROM so you can go back and forth from encrypted to decrypted.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you say you have decrypted your phone because my phone (CyanogenMod 11) says explicitly that the only way to decrypt is a factory reset. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbsHj.png

So in your case I would look if your phone is really decrypted.